# How to update and delete comments from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

First of all, I want to save comments after editing.I'm able to save the other features, but now I need to save comments too because they are in other table.

**Here is my code for comments:**

```
@foreach($event_comm as $comm) 
    <div class="row">                            
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <label class="label" style="color: black">Comment by {{$comm->user->username}}</label>
    <label class="input">
    {{ Form::text('comments', $comm->comments) }}
</label>
@endforeach
```

**My update function**

```
public function update($type, $id)

    {
        /* print_r(Input::all()); die;  */

        if($type == "Opinion")
        {
            $article = \App\Opinion::find($id);
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject');
            $article->public = Request::input('public');
            $article->category_id = Request::input('category_id');
            $article->opinion = Request::input('opinion');
            $article->update();
        }

        if($type == "Event")
        {
            $event_comm = EventComment::where('event_id', $id)->get();

            $article = \App\Event::find($id); 
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject'); 
            $event_comm->comments = Request::input('comments'); 
            $article->public = Request::input('public'); 
            $article->category_id = Request::input('category_id'); 
            $article->website = Request::input('website'); 
            $article->email = Request::input('email'); 
            $article->telephone = Request::input('telephone'); 
            $article->information = Request::input('information'); 
            $article->update(); 
        }


        return redirect(URL::previous())
            ->with(compact('event_comm'));
    }
```

I've already tried to add `$event_comm->comments = Request::input('comments');` but doesn't work.

2.Second problem.I want to also delete comments from database with a button or something like that.I found a route but I'm not sure if works.I need to know how to add this into my file?With a button ?

**My route**

`Route::get('admin/article/deleteComment/{type}/{id}',['as' => 'deleteComment', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@deleteComment']);`

```
public function deleteComment($type, $id)
    {
        if($type == "Event")
        {
            $comment = \App\EventComment::find($id);
        }

        if($type == "Opinion")
        {
            $comment = \App\OpinionComment::find($id);
        }

        $comment->delete();

        return redirect('admin/comments'); 
    }
```

**Button:**

```
<button href="{{ url('deleteComment',$type, $id) }}" role="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this comment?');">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Comment: `<button>` doesn't have the href attribute, change your button into `<a>` tag

Comment: I changed it, but now, on click, I'm redirected to 404 page with this link : `www.link/admin/article/deleteComment`. Any idea ?

Comment: should it be `route('deleteComment', ['type' => $type, 'id' => $id])`? I'm not sure about `url()`, try this `url('deleteComment', [$type, $id])`

Comment: Unfortunately I got this... `Undefined variable: type`

Comment: Here is my `public function viewEvent` : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQVKbQ